# When new data enters the database, will my PowerBI dashboard reflect the changes?

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-synapse

I'm trying to create a dashboard for a client which pulls data from their traditional database into Azure Synapse using Pipelines, where I stored data into Azure DataLakeGen2 as parquet files. Now, i want to visualize data in PowerBI, by connecting PowerBI to Azure DataLakeGen2. Unlike database connections which has import mode or direct query, there is nothing of that sort. I cant afford a dedicated database. What do i do?

Connected PowerBI directly to Azure Datalakegen2. Will dashboard reflect changes directly if there are changes in the parquet files??

Answer (score 0):

I tried connecting to Parquet files to check. there is no option to choose between Import mode or Direct query.
When checking the table properties it is set to Import mode.
[image: import mode]

So it seems that this kind of file connection only supports import mode, and therefore will not automatically reflect the current files status in PowerBI until you run a refresh to import the files again.

Answer (score 0):

DirectQuery supports only some types of data sources.

Try to create new Dataflow in Fabric. Set the automatic or incremental refresh and connect the Dataflow to the Power BI report as DirectQuery. If you use incremental refresh, the data will be updated in time.